# How to make ActionResult in ModelState.IsValid open two url's

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I need to make my application open together with return a new window with another url

**Below ASP.NET MVC code with what I plan to do.
Opens external url and then performs redirection to default system index.**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Details([Bind(Include = "AvisoId,Cliente,Data,Email,Telefone,Observacao,Enviado,Usuario")] Aviso aviso)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(aviso).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();

            Redirect("https://other-site-in-new-window.com");

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(aviso);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry! What is the question ?

Comment: Friend I want to open an external page along with the default index page of the system

Comment: You have to do it from client side. Look into window.open method

Comment: Friends made a mistake, and checking here, I asked a beginner's question, in a hurry I asked a question that is not worth anything, I'm sorry, the solution is simple.......
<input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com/')" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.Net code runs on the web server, and so can't open another tab on the client browser. Because it's not in control of the client's browser - the web server's job is to  the client what they request.

If you want to do something like this, you'll need to have a link on the webpage with target="_blank" for a new tab, and also use javascript to redirect the current page to wherever you want to go once the button is clicked.

Comment: Friends made a mistake, and checking here, I asked a beginner's question, in a hurry I asked a question that is not worth anything, I'm sorry, the solution is simple.......
<input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com/')" />

Answer (score 1):

Opening a new page on the browser is the client's responsibility not the server's (where your asp.net controller) runs.

What you could do however is return the url of the other page you want to open in a

- TempData
- ViewBag
- ViewData
- Cookie

Or possibly in any other form you see fit according to your application. Then on the client side, you retrieve the value of the url you want to open, and open it in a new tab.

Using your code and TempData

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Details([Bind(Include = "AvisoId,Cliente,Data,Email,Telefone,Observacao,Enviado,Usuario")] Aviso aviso)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(aviso).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();

        TempData["ExternalUrl"] = "https://other-site-in-new-window.com";

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(aviso);
}
```

Then in your cshtml page in javascript

```
... 
let externalUrl = '@TempData["ExternalUrl"]';
if(externalUrl) {
   //Do something here
}
...
```